# Sorting dictionary elements from file with capitalization of first letter

Tags: python, list

Hi i am writing a program to read a dictionary from file and then it capital the first letter and sort it alphabetically

What i am trying is to convert dictionary into list. Then i have tried for loop but somehow it is not working

my file contains

```
banana:123
sweet:32
nutella:23
```

my code:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
lst=[]
for line in f.readlines():
    data,price = line.split(":")
    lst.append([data, (price)])
f.close()
```

now when i try for loop to get the index it gives me error

```
for i in range(lst[0:len(lst)][0]):
```

it gives me error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

My question is getting confusing... The main thing i need to be done is that the first letter of each line becomes capital and they get sorted in file alphabetically. 
also please tell me what i am doing wrong in this for loop... I want index to start from [0] to the len[lst]

Comment: You might use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for the range issue just use**

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
```

you provide a list instead of an integer

**for the sorting use this**

```
from operator import itemgetter
f = open("test.txt", "r")
lst = []
for line in f.readlines():
    data, price = line.split(":")
    lst.append([data, (price)])
f.close()
lst = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(1))
print map(lambda x: x[0] + ":" + x[1],  map(lambda x: [x[0].capitalize(), x[1]], lst))

       .....
       .....
 and write to the file
```

Comment: Thanks. For this but about sorting

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sorted` over mapping `capitalize`:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    result = sorted(map(lambda x: x.capitalize().split(":"), f.readlines()))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/PlushAwesomeConfig)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `range`, in your case, only needs an `int` input. You are supplying a `list` input. Specifically, `lst[0:len(lst)][0]` outputs the first element of `lst`, which is a list itself.

To loop over your list of lists by row, you should use `range(len(lst))`:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) for more information on `range` syntax.